# sqlite, how to delete old entries?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I create a table using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pics (X INTEGER NOT NULL, Y INTEGER NOT NULL, Z INTEGER NOT NULL, T INTEGER NOT NULL, Pic BLOB NULL,PRIMARY KEY(X, Y, Z, T))
```

And say I insert 1000 entries into this table using:

```
REPLACE INTO Pics(X, Y, Z, T, Pic)
```

How could I know which entry is the oldest and delete it?
What I would like to achieve is to check whether the entry is more than 1000 rows, if so, when a new row is inserted, the oldest one will be delted.

Comment: Well, I have noted it and asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491307/how-to-insert-a-column-which-is-the-current-total-row-number-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

To be able to tell which rows was inserted first you need to have a notion of ordering.

Since you haven't described any sort of relationship between the values that would imply an ordering, but instead given them names like X, Y and Z, I would hazard a guess that there is no such relationship.

As such, you have no way of telling which of two rows was inserted first.

So you cannot delete the "oldest", because you have no way of identifying those rows.

The follow is some things you could add to your table, but probably not an exhaustive list:

- A timestamp column, telling you *when* a row was added
- An incremental column, telling you *the order* in which rows was added
- Some kind of relationship, like you're inserting rows with an X value that is in order, and then with an Y value that is in order, and with a Z value that is in order, so that you could order by X,Y,Z and get the rows in the initial order

Comment: Well, I have noted it and asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491307/how-to-insert-a-column-which-is-the-current-total-row-number-in-sqlite

Comment: Ah, I think I would like to use the current total row number as a incremental column... Will it work?