# How to insert a column which is the current total row number in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

For a talbe created using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pics (X INTEGER NOT NULL, Y INTEGER NOT NULL, Z INTEGER NOT NULL, T INTEGER NOT NULL, Pic BLOB NULL,PRIMARY KEY(X, Y, Z, T))
```

How can I add one more column that is a `INTEGER` which notes down the current total row number in this table (it tells which row come first)?

How should I write the insert command?

Comment: If you're willing to add another column, why not just add a date/time?

Comment: Sorry, newbie at sql, I want to delete the oldest 100 entries, so I think int incremental column make sence?

Comment: Well, technically you could probably make something work with the [ROWID and the AUTOINCREMENT keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), but I wouldn't recommend it as you have to choose between being unreliable or having a hard limit. You could track your own serial number, but that requires a separate state kept elsewhere. Using timestamps gets around that.

Comment: Can give a simple example which create such a table and insert some things?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a db table with a datetime column with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pics (X INTEGER NOT NULL, Y INTEGER NOT NULL, Z INTEGER NOT NULL, T INTEGER NOT NULL, D DATETIME NOT NULL, Pic BLOB NULL,PRIMARY KEY(X, Y, Z, T))
```

Inserting rows (see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
insert into Pics values (1,2,3,4,strftime('%s','now'), '101010')
```

Getting the latest 100 rows:

```
select * from Pics order by d desc limit 100
```